# Stack Menu Items to be on the left instead of bottom

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have the following menu:

[image]

and I would like it to stack vertically on the left hand side:- something like (sorry for the bad paintjob) :

[image]

HTML Code:-

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn bg-transparent fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg">
      <div class="dropContent">
         <a data-tooltip="View Activity" onclick="" class="btn icon-gls-option m-b-10 m-l-5 d-print-none"><i class="fas fa-book-open"><span class=""></span></i></a>
         <a data-tooltip="Edit" onclick="" class="btn icon-gls-option m-b-10 m-l-5 d-print-none"><i class="fas fa-pen-alt fa-md"></i></a>
         <a data-tooltip="New Task" onclick="" class="btn icon-gls-option m-b-10 m-l-5 d-print-none"><i class="fas fa-tasks fa-md"></i></a> +
         <a data-tooltip="Delete" onclick="" class="btn icon-gls-danger m-b-10 m-l-5 d-print-none"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-md"></i></a>
      </div>
   </button>
</div>
```

CSS Code:-

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin-top: 2px;
    color: black;
}

    .dropContent a {
        display: block;
    }

.dropdown:hover .dropContent {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: try this one
```.dropdown:hover .dropContent {
    display: flex;
    right: 100%;
    z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: @Vlad that does nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can get you started - hover over blue, red menu options appear on left.

`overlayItem` positioned relative so absolute positioning is in relation to it

`hoverMe` this is the blue blob. Hover over it, dropdown is displayed as flex to achieve row of menu options

`dropdown` positioned absolute and moved in line with `hoverMe` using transform. Width is fit-content so flex row doesn't take up more than the content inside the div

```css
.overlayItem {
  position: relative;
  
  margin-left: 400px;
  
  height: 50px;
}

.hoverMe {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.hoverMe:hover + .dropdown {
  display: flex;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  
  gap: 10px;

  height: 100%;

  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  
  background-color: red;
  
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlayItem">
  <div class="hoverMe"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <p>item 1</p>
    <p>item 2</p>
    <p>item 3</p>
    <p>item 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```